# How to write this in python

Tags: python, gps

I am not super experienced in writing code. Could someone help me out?

I am trying to write some simple python to work with some GPS coordinates.  Basically I want it to check if the gps is +or- ten feet to my a point then print if it is true.  Think I got that part figured out but I am not sure about this part.  After the gps = the point I want it to only print I am here once until the next time it is true.

Basically set a 10 foot bubble around a gps coordinate, if I walk into that bubble print “I am here” Just once until I walk out and reenter the bubble.   Does that make sense?

```
if "point_lat-10feet" <= gps_lat <= "point_lat+10" and "point_log-10" <= gps_log <= "point_log+10"
Print "You are at point 1"
```

## Update

Finally had some time to work on this project, here is how it ended up
I used the package utm 0.4.0 to convert the lat and long to Utm north and east.

```
north, east, zone, band = utm.from_latlon(gpsc.fix.latitude, gpsc.fix.longitude)
northgoal, eastgoal, heading = (11111, 22222, 90)

# +- 50 degree 
headerror = 50

#bubble size 10m 
pointsize = 10

flag = False

if ((north - northgoal) ** 2) + ((east - eastgoal) ** 2) <= (pointsize ** 2) and  ((heading - headerror) % 360) <= gpsc.fix.track <= ((heading + headerror) % 360):
            if not flag :
                print "Arriving at point 1" , north, east, gpsc.fix.track, gpsc.fix.speed
                flag = True
            else:
                print "Still inside point 1"

        else:
           # print "Outside point 1"
            flag = False
```

I have this in a while loop with a few other points. There Is probably a better way but hey this works. 
Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Thanks everyone! This really helped me out and got me going in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to revise your check. If you want to check if you are within a 10-foot radius bubble, you need to use Pythagoras, otherwise you are checking if you are within a 20x20-foot square. For example, if you are 9 feet away from the point in both latitude and longitude, that means you are actually 12.73 feet away from your target point, which is outside your 10-foot bubble, but your code will produce a false positive.

The formula for a circle is `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`, where `x` and `y` are deltas along orthogonal axes, and `r` is your radius (10 feet.)

However, keep in mind that GPS coordinates (I assume we are talking geodetic, since you mention lat and long) are given in degrees, since geodetic coordinates are spherical. So, you will need to project your position as well as the target position into a Cartesian system such as UTM. Then you can revise your check as follows:

`if (x - target_x) ** 2 + (y - target_y) ** 2 <= 3.048 ** 2`

Where `x` is your X coordinate, `target_x` is the target X coordinate, etc. The value 3.048 is 10 feet expressed in meters. I used meters because UTM coordinates are always expressed in meters.

Next, if I understand you correctly, you only want to print a message once you've entered the bubble, and only print it again if you leave the bubble and re-enter. In that case, you simply need a flag that you set and unset as you enter and leave the desired area, respectively. Robert has it right, so you would have something like this:

```
# Initialize flag here once
printFlag = False

...

# Check if we're in the target area
if (x - target_x) ** 2 + (y - target_y) ** 2 <= 3.048 ** 2:
    if not printFlag :
        print "You are at point 1"
        printFlag = True
else:
    printFlag = False
```

This will print the message then, as long as you remain within the area, won't print the message again. However, there is one last thing to keep in mind about this: unassisted GPS is only good to about +/-3 meters, which is almost exactly equal to your radius. This means you have to be careful about how you perform your check, otherwise you will get a lot of "You are at point 1" messages when you get near the target area, as your apparent position can jump +/-3 meters in both axes, even if you're standing still. You may have to use a running average or something similar in order to improve your raw accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in a condition check within the if.

Not language specific, but the general idea

```
if <in coord condition>
    if <not printed condition>
       print
       set print condition
else
    clear print condition
```

Answer (score 0):

If your syntax &c were corrected (those strings are definitely wrong) you'd be checking for a square, not a circle.

Assuming `point_lat`, `gps_lat`, &c, are all numbers (not strings), and expressed in feet (and assuming `_log` is a typo for `_lon`, standing for "longitude"), you'd need:

```
import math

if math.hypot(point_lat - gps_lat, point_lon - gps_lon) < 10:
    print("You are at point 1")
```

`math.hypot` applies Pythagoras' theorem to compute the hypothenuse of the right-angled triangle with the given other two sides -- which also happens to be the distance between the two points.  "The two points are less than 10 feet apart" defines a **circle**, as desired.

If the latitudes and longitudes are not numbers measured in feet, you'll need to make them such, e.g converting from strings to `float` and/or using the appropriate scale factors.

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic solution would be to have a starting point and calculate individual instances to see if it meets the condition.

For expediency let's import **pyproj** to calculate distance on a WGS-84 geoid.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" banana """
from pyproj import Geod

def do_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    """Simple, but accurate, distance"""
    try:
        geoid = Geod(ellps='WGS84')
        bearing_to, bearing_fro, distance = geoid.inv(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)
        distance *= 3.2808399  # because you wanted feet
        if distance <= 10:
            print('I am here')
        else:
            print('Still off {0:.0f} feet. Head {1:.0f}° from North'.format(distance, bearing_fro % 360))

    except Exception as error:
        print("Can't calculate because: ", error)

    print(bearing_to % 360, bearing_fro % 360, distance)

lat1 = -15.559752
lon1 = -146.240726
lat2 = -15.561200
lon2 = -146.241407

dd = do_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
```

`lat1` and `lon1` would be your start, or *goal*, `lat2` and `lon2` would be the position to test if it meets condition.